# Building efficient left anti-semi joins in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been converting a long-standing, gnarly sproc into EF to get it into a more testable and maintainable position. Most of it has gone fairly well, except for this part here:

```
select p.idProduct from products p
where
// {some random filtering bringing us down to a manageable number of rows}
AND p.idProduct NOT IN (SELECT idProduct from productsShipped)
```

which I have converted into this:

```
        var results = dbc.products.Where(p =>
            p.warehouse == warehouse
            && p.BarConversion.Bar.BarDate > minDate
            && !dbc.productsShipped.Any(ps => ps.idInventory == p.idInventory)
            //&& p.productsShipped == null
            && p.OPR.Order.Payment != null
            && !(p.OPR.Order.PaymentType == 5 &&
                 (p.OPR.Order.Payment.paymentStatus == null ||
                  p.OPR.Order.Payment.paymentStatus != "accepted"))
            && p.OPR.Order.OrderSla.expectedShipDate <= dueDateCutoff);
```

The issue I'm having is that the productsShipped table is absolutely enormous. In raw SQL, the where clause must understand that it does not need to pull the entirety of the productsShipped table and instead only fetches products which relate to the previous query. The EF equivalent breaks it down into a subquery and asks for every entry in the productsShipped table, causing the query to take more than five minutes, as opposed to the couple of seconds it takes to run without this filter. I've tried adding a relationship between the two entities with similar results.

Is there a way I can force Entity to make a proper left outer exclusive join rather than a subquery or similarly improve performance, or am I forced to either take this performance hit or push part of my logic into a difficult-to-test sproc?

Comment: If you structure your query properly, EF will return the result in a single query. Cannot tell the issue here unless you show the complete EF query. There might be something else slowing your result.

Comment: navigation properties result in left outer joins. Your problem most likely is the massive or statement (probably with outer apply) created by the any. You could try converting it to a .Contains for the equivalent IN statement. the query performance however is most likely determined by your db schema and optimizations, not necessarily EF query building (unless the provider builds badly optimizable queries)

Comment: I've updated to show the full query. @DevilSuichiro I've tried using a navigation property, but it causes the query to never complete.

Comment: What is a "left outer exclusive join" exactly? I don't see that in common SQL Join types... Also, which EF are you using?

Comment: @NetMage Sorry, it's been a while since I worked heavily with SQL. I mean a join which takes all rows in the left table which cannot join to the right table. In https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zgg.png, it is the join in the center left.

Comment: BTW, did you mean to use `p` instead of `i` in the other conditions on your `Where`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method (from MSDN) for a left anti-semijoin:

```
public static IQueryable<TLeft> LeftAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight>(this IQueryable<TLeft> left, IQueryable<TRight> right, Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, bool>> predicate) {
    var leftPrm = predicate.Parameters[0];
    var rightPrm = predicate.Parameters[1];

    // retrieve methods
    var anyMethod = ((Func<IQueryable<TRight>, bool>)Queryable.Any).Method;
    var whereMethod = ((Func<IQueryable<TRight>, Expression<Func<TRight, bool>>, IQueryable<TRight>>)Queryable.Where).Method;

    // l => !right.Where(r => predicate(l, r)).Any()
    var leftPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TLeft, bool>>(
        Expression.Not(
            Expression.Call(anyMethod,
                Expression.Call(whereMethod,
                    Expression.Constant(right),
                    Expression.Lambda<Func<TRight, bool>>(predicate.Body, rightPrm)))),
        leftPrm);

    return left.Where(leftPredicate);
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
var results2 = dbc.products.LeftAntiSemiJoin(dbc.productsShipped, (p, ps) => p.idInventory == ps.idInventory)
                  .Where(p =>
                        p.warehouse == warehouse &&
                        p.BarConversion.Bar.BarDate > minDate &&
                        p.OPR.Order.Payment != null &&
                        !(p.OPR.Order.PaymentType == 5 &&
                          (p.OPR.Order.Payment.paymentStatus == null ||
                           p.OPR.Order.Payment.paymentStatus != "accepted")) &&
                        p.OPR.Order.OrderSla.expectedShipDate <= dueDateCutoff);
```

Perhaps it will be faster?

Answer (score 0):

While I was ultimately unable to get Entity to generate the SQL the way I wanted, I found I was able to run a separate query to get the necessary data from productsShipped, drop that into a dictionary, and do the lookup from there.